# Countdown Timer that can be extended by user input?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, countdown

I am trying to make a little game.
I need a timer, that starts counting down in the background when the game begins (it shows the lifespan of a bonfire).
There is no need to print the remaining duration (`fire_time`) every second, but the user should be able to input a command (like `fire`) to get the remaining seconds.
The user should also be able to input words that add different amounts of seconds to the timer (like `"paper"`, `"wood"`, etc.)

I've tried to create a timer in a thread that is counting down with the following code:

```
for seconds in range(fire_time, 0, -1):
    fire_timer = Timer(0, fire_time_calc, [fire_time])
    fire_timer.start()
    #print(f"'Fire_time' aus for-loop = {fire_time}")
    time.sleep(1)
    fire_time -= 1
```

and I've got a function that is called, that prints the time (`fire_time_calc`).
Currently the function is only to show how the countdown is proceeding, but I don't know if I really need it.

Currently the timer is working fine because it counts down to zero.
The problem is, that no user input is allowed until it reaches zero.
The variable `fire_time` needs to be updated and accessible outside of the `for`-loop to add time to the countdown...

Anybody got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think using a `threading.Timer` is a good approach for doing what you want. All they do block the specified number of seconds before calling the specified function. The current implementation does this internally by waiting on a `threading.Event` with a timeout set to the delay time and there's no way to change the timeout value once the waiting has begun. A better way to accomplish things might be to define your own `CountDownTimer` subclass of `Thread` that was implemented in a different way — one that allowed them to be extended like you desire.

Comment: Hi Martineau, thank you very much for the comment. I understand now, what the Timer does. I first thought it worked in a different way. When I do what you suggested (define my own CountDownTimer as a subclass of Thread), will this be started in a new Thread because it is a subclass of Thread?

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible to get the remaining time from the currently running timer, save it in a variable, cancel this timer, add the wanted amount of seconds to what is saved in the variable and start a new timer with this new amount of seconds from the variable? This was my idea of "updating the duration". But by now, I don't know how to get the remaining duration of the timer...

Comment: No, not the way the `Timer` class is currently implemented in the `threading` module (or at least not easily). See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/threading.py#L1242). Its `run()` method does a `self.finished.wait(self.interval)`, and `self.finished` is a `threading.Event`, so it would require hacking one of those to do what you want (if it's even possible). Also note that all this is a private implementation detail, so may change in the future. I suggest that you implement your own `Timer` class that allows you to do what you want.